# Throughput Controller is better choice or Parallel Thread Groups?

Tags: performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I have 4 Test Scenarios so I have created 4 throughput controllers under single Thread Group. My expectation is to run all of Throughput Controllers in parallel with some percentage.

My observation is all throughput controllers are not starting at a time, unlike Parallel Thread Groups.  It gets divided as per total percentage but it does not run in a parallel manner.  My finding as below:
1. Thread Group - Number Of Threads - 32
2. Under Thread Group-> 4 Throughput Controllers - each with 25 %

If you observe the listener -> Aggregate Report, you will notice that samplers present under Throughput Controller-1 get executed at first then second and so on. So they get executed Upside down. **Running Thread/TotalThread** count remains **8/32** till the end of the test.

Although each sampler is getting executed for 25% (8 times) of total threads, this does not suffice the requirement of running all 32 threads in Parallel.

Can anyone guide me on how to build a test plan to run all Test Scenarios in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter threads (virtual users) execute [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))

The most possible explanation is that you don't have enough iterations defined in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) so you're running into the situation when some samplers have already finished their work and stopped and some haven't been yet started.

The solution will be just providing more loops in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level:

[image]

this way when thread reaches the last Sampler it will start over so when Ramp-Up phase finishes you should see 32 online users in [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener

[image]

Check out [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected/) article for more comprehensive explanation if needed.